Common mode choke DC resistance measurement technique
I am trying to measure common mode choke DC resistance to find out conduction loss due to DC current. I am using this (product link) one in particular. I measured the resistance between pin 3 and pin 4 of IC with a Fluke 177 multimeter. Pin 3 and 4 is connected to the DC source on each side and Pin 1 and 2 is connected to ground.
But the problem is the resistance I measured is quite a bit higher than the datasheet resistance. That makes me question- is this a good enough way to measure an inductor or common mode choke DC resistance- just using a multimeter (and waiting a few seconds)?
Thank you for your responses.

You didn't say which component out of the 10 covered by your linked datasheet you are using, but the largest one has a maximum resistance of about 0.37 ohms. This is too small to be measured accurately by most handheld multimeters, which in my experience often read 0.2 or 0.3 ohms just from lead and contact resistance.
You should try to find a meter that offers a 4-wire resistance setting. This method delivers the stimulus current through a separate set of wires from those used to sense the resistor voltage, eliminating the lead and contact resistance effects from the measurement.
If you are measuring in-circuit you should also take note of any parallel current paths through your circuit that could be affecting your measurement, or measure the component off-board before loading it on the PCB.

I am using the second one from the top-PAC6006.104NLT for which the typical resistance stated in the datasheet is 3.8m ohms. Also, I was just not measuring in-circuit, just measuring across the component without any connection.
So, whenever I intend to measure a small resistance in the m ohm range, I should use a 4-wire measurement technique? That makes sense, because I have been trying to measure DC resistance of inductors and I am either getting 0.2 or 0.3 ohm as you mentioned. So surprising!

@Bee16 Not surprising at all. Most instruments don't show zero ohms when shorting out their leads, and they typically show from at least 0.1 ohms and up to over 1 ohm.

You are right. Also, the fluke-177 can't do m ohm, that's why I was getting 0.2-0.3V. Lesson learnt.

@Bee16, 3.8m ohms is definitely 4-wire measurement territory. If you really want an accurate number you might need a specialized milliohmmeter. But that's also in the range where issues like trace resistance and via resistance might be comparable --- so if that level of loss is important you may need to look at a lot more than just the choke's DCR.

Fortunately, I have some 4 wire measurement instruments available in the lab. So, I will be using those. Thanks.

For the lack of a milli-ohmmeter, I use my lab power supply with constant current capability, set the current to 1 ampere, and the voltage to no more than 1V.
Then I use the 2V or 200mV range on my multimeter, whose voltage in millivolts translates directly into the resistance in milliohms.
I can even move the voltmeter probes or the current source clips around to see exactly how much resistance I get at a certain length of a MOSFET leg, for example, but there is no difference if you move voltmeter leads behind the current source attachments because there is no current flow and thus no voltage drop except in between them.
It is similar to the 4-wire or Kelvin method.
You can also use an LCR meter which typically has a resolution of 0.01 ohm or 10 milliohms.
There is another method I use instead of the lab power supply:
the program Daqarta for Windows, which includes an LCR measuring capability that gives you 1 milliohm resolution by just using a soundcard and a simple homemade extension for it (instructions on their website).
You may need to learn a bit about using it, but it's worth it.
It is free for 30 days, and then you can simply re-install it after 30 days to get another time extension.
Here is the link to their LCR section:
https://www.daqarta.com/dw_0o0z.htm
The LCR method is often filled with noise and unstable at the lowest resistances (below 100 milliohms) because the signal voltage is the lowest and the signal/noise ratio becomes worse.
The DC method is usually very stable and accurate.

To measure milliohms of resistance you need a special 4-wire ohmmeter that deals with thermocouple generated voltages due to dissimilar metals (Seebeck effect). Only high-end 4-wire ohmmeters have a function to null out the thermocouple generated voltage which will mess up the resistance measurement.
Best bet is using @EdinFifić's method of pumping a few amperes through the coil and measuring the voltage. At 3.8 mohms, you'll need >10 A.
